# Add openssl dependency using g++

Tags: c++, openssl, g++

I got Windows 10 64 bit laptop

I am trying to build [ed25519-donna](https://github.com/floodyberry/ed25519-donna) by executing:

```
g++ -o ed25519 Core/src/main/jni/ed25519/ed25519.c -I C:/OpenSSL/include -L C:/OpenSSL/lib/
```

But I am getting the below error:

> ...ed25519.c:(.text+0x120b0): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

It complains about missing open ssl crypto files, but I don't know how to solve this. Also been trying to append: `-lssl -lcrypto` but it didn't help

Comment: This is expected. `ed25519.c` is not a complete program you can run.

Comment: @n.m. My goal is to use it as a library in Java jni project, what can I do?

Comment: The command you have used builds an executable. To build a library you need different command line arguments. I'm not familiar with JNI so I won't try and guess what exactly you need. I only suggest you use a C compiler, because it's a C library, not a C++ one.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with C, can you please link me to how I need to compile a library with C?

Comment: Perhaps asking a question like "how do I compile an OpenSSL based C library for use with JNI" and using appropriate tags will attract the right crowd.

Comment: @n.m. Oh wow, I got it, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to n.m [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674005/add-openssl-dependency-using-g?noredirect=1#comment84347177_48674005) pointing out that it should be a library, I found a solution:

```
g++ -Wall -g -c Core/src/main/jni/ed25519/ed25519.c -I C:/OpenSSL/include -o Core/out/jni/ed25519.o
```